# Using DCount function with a query linked to a control

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

The following code is giving me a syntax error message. I would like to use the DCount function on the current event of a form to count records in a table where the value on the control 'TeamID' is equal to that in field 'teamID' in the table 'tblCompetency06'

```
Me.etcRecordNumber.Caption = "Record " & Me.CurrentRecord & " of " & DCount("ID", "tblCompetency06") WHERE [tblcompetency06].[teamID]= '" & me.Teamid & "'"
```

Comment: It is simply: ' Complilation error: Syntax error'

Comment: (i get the impression that the Where clause is causing this problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be two reasons, one you are using the wrong syntax for DCount. Second you are using/comparing a Number data type and you are comparing with a String. Try the following.

```
Me.etcRecordNumber.Caption = "Record " & Me.CurrentRecord & " of " & _
                              DCount("*", "tblCompetency06", "[teamID]= " & me.Teamid)
```